# makefile: how to delete multiple files with multiple endings

Tags: makefile

I was unable to find a way to get this done in a makefile, perhaps someone can help me out:

I have two lists one with filenames

```
$FILES = file1 file2 ...
```

and one with suffixes

```
$SUF = .suf1 .suf2 ...
```

and I want to get a list like

```
file1.suf1 file2.suf1 file1.suf2 file2.suf2 ...
```

how can I do this in a makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything can always be done in a makefile, by definition.

First of all, your variable syntax is incorrect.  Should be without `$`

```
FILES := file0 file1
```

Note that you should always use `:=` unless you have a good reason to use `=`.  (Also, if an interviewee started their array with `1` I would say "no hire".  But that's maybe just me).

Now, one solution to your question is

```
$(foreach suf, $(SUF),$(addsuffix $(suf), $(FILES)))
```

Comment: Be careful with spaces placed around commas/etc. in makefiles. They are occasionally significant in ways that will not do what you want (they will end up in your output in places you might not expect). The snippet above is fine but `$(foreach suf , $(SUF),$(addsuffix $(suf), $(FILES)))` would silently result in an output string of n (length of SUF) copies of the contents of FILES.

Comment: @EtanReisner exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following will work.

```
FILES = file1 file2 file3 file4

SUF = .suf1 .suf2 .suf3 .suf4

$(info $(foreach s,$(SUF),$(foreach f,$(FILES),$f$s)))

$(info $(foreach s,$(SUF),$(addsuffix $s,$(FILES))))
```